# Fudging QWebEngine to run Javascript code 'synchronously'

Tags: qt, qtwebengine, qeventloop

I am using `QWebEngine` and I would like to run some Javascript synchronously! Or at least pretend to. So I came up with an ol' classic, using `QEventLoop` to wait. I call this code from my `QWebEngineView` derived class:

```
void MyView::doSomething()
{
    QEventLoop loop;

    const QString jsCode = "console.log('hi from javascript!');";
    page()->runJavaScript(jsCode,[&](const QVariant&)
    {
        qDebug() << "script done!";
        loop.quit();
    });

    qDebug() << "calling loop.exec()";
    loop.exec();
    qDebug() << "finished loop.exec()";
}
```

However this does not work as the lambda is never executed. Regardless of whether or not this is a complete hack (it is), I'm curious as to why it doesn't work.

And in the spirit of this being a complete hack, is there a "better" way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: did you add debug output/debug to the lambda to check if get's executed? and could you verify your js actually gets executed properly? Try something simple like `console.log("test")`

Comment: @Felix I will update the question but yes, I have debug messages to confirm my observation.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution? I have been banging my head against the wall for the last week trying to do this.

Comment: @Akiva No, I did not. I ended up redesigning what I had to do. `QWebEngine`'s lack of any synchronous support is one reason I've started using `QWebKit` again. (Well, that and the issues it has with publishing to the Mac App Store).

Comment: You do understand that doing synchronous anything typically leads to terrible user experience, right? I certainly hope you're running that synchronous stuff in some worker thread, and that it's not something the UI would be blocked waiting for. In any case, you'd likely do much better simply accepting asynchronicity of our world, and learning how to write async-aware code. It's not hard once you accept that it's how the world is. Async.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica I'm not sure what part of "regardless of whether or not this is a complete hack (it is), I'm curious as to why it doesn't work" you didn't understand.

Comment: Sometimes the designs are slightly biased to make such hacks not work :)